# Fade in my images with my javascript slideshow

Tags: javascript

How could I fade in my images in my javascript slideshow, I'm using this code which I found on a tutorial, any help is appreciated. http://jsfiddle.net/cuga9mbe/1/

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var step=1
    function slideit() {
        document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")
        if(step<3)
        step++
        else
        step=1
        setTimeout("slideit()",2500)
    }
    slideit()
    </script>
```

Comment: Um. Could you create a fiddle or something? also, `setTimeout("slideit()",2500)` makes no sense. You can't pass off a string to the first parameter of setTimeout. You should pass the function. `setTimeout(slideit, 2500)` **notice how there are no paranthesis.**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cuga9mbe/1/ @Menixator

Comment: @Matanya Okay thanks, I will check out som jQuery slideshows then. Thanks anyways

Comment: @Menixator It is possible to pass a string to setTimeout - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout. However this is seriously not recommended so you are still correct in saying to pass the function.

Answer (score 1):

this code doesn't lend itself to using any transition effects as it changes the `src` property of the image itself which occurs instantaneously. If you want a fade transition you should stack the images on top of each other using absolute positioning and then fade in one image while fading out the other. It is recommended to use jquery, which already has built-in transition functions, such as `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`.

Also, rather then calling `setTimeout` recursively, you should use `setInterval`.

a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cuga9mbe/9/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cuga9mbe/7/ - fixed the transition from the last to the first image, and removed hard-coded length.

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed it myself. I believe the `fadeOut` can simply be done on all of the images. No need to calculate the visible one. Alternatively a `:visible` filter can be used.